# Bootsrapmodal not opening on seting it on other button

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Why isn't when I click on login button it open the login modal but on sign up it opens I added the same on both just rename login on eto loginModel  but it don't work while sign up work as expected I am using bootstrap modal

Header.php

```
<button class="btn btn-success ml-2 mt-2 data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#loginModal">login </button>  
      <button class="btn btn-success mx-2 mt-2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#signupModal">signup </button>  
      </div>
   
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>';
include 'partials/_loginmodal.php';
include 'partials/_signupmodal.php';
```

_loginmodal.php

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >
 Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
       <h5 class="modal-title" id="loginModalLabel"></h5>
       <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
       ...
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

_signupmodal.php

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="signupModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="signupModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="signupModalLabel">Signup</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
<button class="btn btn-success ml-2 mt-2 data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#loginModal">login </button>
                                        ^
```

There is double quote missing. It should be:

```
<button class="btn btn-success ml-2 mt-2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#loginModal">login </button>
                                        ^
```